# Matlab Plot; one data set, two axis, date

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot a single data set in terms of dates (x axis), I would like to add on the second (top) x axis with interval of time in days. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create another axes on top of the first, and put the xaxis location at the 'top' for that. Here is a small example.

```
% Some example data
d = linspace(now,now-7,7);
y = randn(size(d));

% Create first axes
ax1 = axes;
plot(d,y);
datetick(ax1, 'x', 'yy-mm-dd')

% Create second axes
ax2 = axes;
plot(d,y,'Visible', 'off'); % No need to show doubles
set(ax2, 'Position', ax1.Position, 'XAxisLocation', 'top', ...
    'Color', 'none' ,'YTick', []);
datetick(ax2, 'x', 'ddd')
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but I need to display elapsed days on the top x axis. the following failed.
clear; close all;
% Some example data over 150 days
d=linspace(now,now-150, 20); x=linspace(1,20,20);
y = randn(size(d));
% Create first axes
ax1 = axes;
plot(d,y);
datetick(ax1, 'x', 'dd-mm-yy')
xlabel('Date');
% Create second axes
ax2 = axes;
plot(x,y,'Visible', 'off'); % No need to show doubles
set(ax2, 'Position', ax1.Position, 'XAxisLocation', 'top', ...
    'Color', 'none' ,'YTick', [],'Xtick',linspace(1,20,20));
xlabel('days')

Comment: Do you want to display every one of the 150 days? Don't forget the last part from my example `datetick(ax2, 'x', 'ddd')` in your code. The `'Xtick',linspace(1,20,20)` is not needed.